# Logistic regression: class probabilities

Tags: r, logistic

I am using logistic regression to solve the classification problem.

```
g = glm(target ~ ., data=trainData, family = binomial("logit"))
```

There are two classes (target): 0 and 1

When I run the prediction function, it returns probabilities.

```
p = predict(g, testData, type = "response")
```

However, it is not clear to me how to understand which class has been assigned?

```
Real  p 

1   0.17568578
1   0.41698474
1   0.19151927
1   0.25587242
1   0.25604452
0   0.39976069
0   0.39910282
0   0.16879320
```

I appreciate if someone can explain me how this works based on the above example. Thanks

Comment: These are the predicted probabilities of each observation to be 1 (i.e. success).

Comment: You are the one who gets to choose the threshold for a decision based on the costs of mis-classification in either direction.

Comment: @ David Arenburg: Ok, but what is the threshold, 0.5? E.g. what does 0.41 mean if the real class is 1? Does it mean that the entry has been classified as the class 0?

Comment: @BondedDust: But how do I select the threshold for my particular example? Does 0.41 mean 1, because it's maximum value?

Comment: If you pick 0.5 as the threshold (which is often what is done, but such practice should be criticised as a naive choice) then it implies that the cost of mis-classification is equal in both directions.

Comment: 0.41 means what it means. This entry has 0.41 probability to be a success based  on the fitted model. I'm truly confused on what you asking. You do realize that you are calculating the expected `target` (i.e. `E(target)`) rather a classifier, do you?

Comment: Sorry, but I misunderstand the outputs of this classifier. Could you please suggest a clear simple tutorial for dummies? I cannot understand how should I extract assigned class values from these outputs. E.g. if the entry has 0.41 success, then it means that it relates to the class 0 (if the threshold is 0.5). But how can I know what is the right threshold?

Comment: @BondedDust: If the threshold is 0.5, then all entries in my example belong to the class 0?

Comment: 0.41 should be the probability the observation goes to class 1, so, if you choose 0.5 threshold, you finally assign it to class 0.

Comment: @BondedDust: Do I understand correctly that I can use AUC to know how many entries have been classified correctly?

Comment: No. AUC is not the proportion of correctly classified objects (a measure sometimes called "accuracy".) Please read up on this in CrossValidated.com since it is a statistical question and not a coding issue.

Comment: There is no standard threshold but as you have the target in your data, try threshold near to percentage of 1 in target and check where you get good classification. Use that threshold. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 11):

The predicted values only tell you how likely it is that an observation belongs to the class coded as 1 given its explanatory variables. For classification, you need to find a threshold $t$ which in some sense is optimal for your problem. This is e.g. affected by monetary costs or ethical boundaries.

If you don't have any of these costs or boundaries, i.e. is a cost function, one criterion could be to minimize the sum of the error frequencies. For this the following two terms are important:

Sensitivity denotes the fraction of positives that were correctly specified for a given $t$.

Specificity denotes the fraction of negatives that were correctly specified for a given $t$.

Denote $s_0$ as Senstitvity and $s_1$ as Specificty, minimizing the sum of the error frequencies is equivalent to finding maximum $s_0(t) + s_1(t)$ for all thresholds $t$.

Here, I recommend to use the `pROC` package in R. It provides a very useful function called `roc`. See the sample code below. Here, `response` is your vector of ones and zeros and `predictor` your predictions. Moreover, the code produces also the corresponding ROC curve and adds a vertical line where the optimal threshold was found.

**Please note**: You provided very little data so I simulated some myself to get more different Sensitivities and Specificities. You can find the code for the simulated data below the picture.

```
rm(list = ls()) # clear work space

#install and load package
install.packages("pROC")
library(pROC)

#apply roc function
analysis <- roc(response=p$Real, predictor=p$p)

#Find t that minimizes error
e <- cbind(analysis$thresholds,analysis$sensitivities+analysis$specificities)
opt_t <- subset(e,e[,2]==max(e[,2]))[,1]

#Plot ROC Curve
plot(1-analysis$specificities,analysis$sensitivities,type="l",
ylab="Sensitiviy",xlab="1-Specificity",col="black",lwd=2,
main = "ROC Curve for Simulated Data")
abline(a=0,b=1)
abline(v = opt_t) #add optimal t to ROC curve
opt_t #print t
```

[image]

```
##Simulate Data
set.seed(123456)
n <- 10000
q <- 0.8

#Simulate predictions
Real <- c(sample(c(0,1), n/2, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-q,q)),
        sample(c(0,1), n/2, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7,0.3)))

#Simulate Response
p <- c(rep(seq(0.4,0.9, length=100), 50),
    rep(seq(0.2,0.6, length=100), 50))
p <- data.frame(cbind(Real, p))
```

Comment: So in your example, `opt_t` (which seems to be identical to Youden's Index) = 0.5964646. Does that mean that Klausos should classify any observation with a predicted probability > 0.5964646 as "Class 1" and any observation with a predicted probability < 0.5964646 as "Class 0"?

Comment: Related to that, the vertical abline at 0.5964646 on the ROC Curve offers a nice visual of the threshold, but I'm curious why it is on the x-axis instead of the y-axis, and how to interpret it in relation to the y-axis (as it seems to intersect the y-axis at the same value as the specificity value produced by `coords(analysis, "best", best.method = "youden")` in the `pROC` package, but in the plot produced from your code the y-axis is labeled as the "sensitivity".

Answer (score 4):

Put simply/blunty a logistic regression model *is not a classifier*.  It is a model for the probability parameter of the binomial distribution.  This is why `predict()` gives probabilities.

In order to make it a classifier you need to specify a function converts probabilities into classes.  Choosing a cutoff is one way - although probably not ideal for a large number of predictions.  Taking your example, and the "naive" cutoff of 0.5 leads to all observations being classified as $0$.  This is despite the model expectation of the number of $1$ classes to be about $2.5$

A better approach could be taking a randomised decision - generate a bernoulli random variable with the probability,  and set that as your classifier.

Comment: When/why would the randomization procedure described at the last paragraph be better than using a threshold?

Comment: A randomised decision is more likely to give predictions consistent with "global" model expectations.  In the example given, a randomised decision will give about $2$ or $3$ predictions of $1$.  Perhaps a more general idea is that when doing a large number of predictions, applying the optimal prediction for each individual observation, does not necessarily lead to an optimal prediction for all observations taken together.  A very basic example is a coin with $P(H)=0.51$.  If you are prediction the next toss, then $H$ is best.  When predicting the next $1,000$ might not want to predict all $H$

Answer (score 0):

For finding which level is 0 and which level is 1, use `levels()` function on the response column.

You can change the order of levels by using the `factor()` function:

```
response <- factor(response,levels=c(level2,level1))
```

Comment: That's not the question Klausos was asking.